# too many connectios for role. ElephantSQl

Tags: postgresql, nest, prisma

I am using Elephant sql, and whenever I want to migrate my prisma schema but the error happens:
[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: How many connections are you trying to make?  How many are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I use `npx prisma db push` and it works!